# Message "No pending update" after update.php (update module)

Tags: database, updating

Today I updated the security update for the "views".

I always follow the steps for updating a module or core:

1) put site in maintenance mode 
2) FTP the files
3) go to link site/update.php

But sometimes i get the message "no pending updates"... after step 3...

When I googled this I read something about some updates don't require a update of the Database.

So, ... If I see this message can i leave step 3 when i update my next site?
I think so, but i prefer a conformation of a Drupal expert ;-)

Thanks for reading and all the info you will leave behind here :-)
Kristof

Answer (score 1):

The "no pending updates" message means that there are no DB updates to be run. At that point, you are safe to go on with your normal process, which may include a few more steps:

1. If you use features, check to see if they have been overridden.
2. Clear caches.
3. Take your site out of maintenance mode.

Comment: Thanks RoloDMonkey! I do understand :-) So before the message "no pending updates" there are also important things that happens, like clearing cache first...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the update if you need to run update.php. Personally, if I know a update doesn't contain a db update, I won't run update.php.

That being said, if your unsure if a db update is necessary, you might wanna run it just to be sure.